# libexif example to add a small Xml document in the exif data

Tags: c, jpeg, exif, libexif

Any libexif user/developer that could point me in the right direction on what are the appropriate call for adding a small custom XML document in the exif meta data of a JPG image ?

I have been googling around for a while and can't figure it out.

I am open to any other opensource library that will let me do that as long as it is C based.

Answer (score 2):

You can embed any data into an EXIF data block in a JPG. There is no size limit that I am aware of, you just split it into mutliple EXIF data blocks if required.

You don't even need libexif. You can do it all manually in C code by programmatically doing the following (note that this only works with JPG files that already have other EXIF data in it):

Basically your JPG file (if it already has an EXIF header in it) will start with something like:

```
0xFF 0xD8
```

Then the very first Exif header will start with this:

```
0xFF 0xE0
```

The next comes the length of the Exif data block which is two bytes here:

```
0x00 0x10 //In this case it is 16 bytes (0x0010) long and it INCLUDES these two bytes of the header
```

Next comes the Exif data block's actual data (yours may be different). Note that it is 14 bytes long (or 14+**2** = 16bytes, or 0x0010 as shown above):

```
0x4A 0x46 0x49 0x46 0x00 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x60 0x00 0x60 0x00 0x00
```

Now you can insert your XML Exif data block after this header starting with an exif data identifier (always the same):

```
0xFF 0xE1
```

Then the size of your XML file in bytes + **2** (note that if your file is larger than  0xFFFE in size then you must split it up into multiple EXIF data blocks):

```
0x07 0x7D //In this case it is 1917bytes long or 0x077D
```

Then insert your xml directly into the JPG at this point and leave the rest of the file as is.

See the picture below for a visual explanation (just right click and view image if you can't read it):

[image: Example of XML file inserted into EXIF data of JPG]

Here is my JPG with my dummy XML file in it. Right click, save, open it in a Hex editor and look for yourself:

[Sample JPG with XML in EXIF data block](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15883001/Result2.jpg)

At the end just check you can still open the JPG and if you can you've succeeded.

Here is a quick example in C++ (note I haven't debugged the code, just wrote it from memory so be warned!):

```
char yourdata[]="<xml> contents to </add>";
long yourdatalen = 0x18;

//open file
char * file;
long filelen=0;
std::ifstream infile;
infile.open("yourjpg.jpg",std::ios::binary| std::ios::in);

//find size of file
infile.seekg (0, ios::end);
filelen = infile.tellg();
infile.seekg (0, ios::beg);

//read contents of file
file = new char [filelen];
infile.read(file,filelen);
infile.close();

//lets parse through the file and find any exif headers
long x=0;
if ((file[0]==0xFF) && (file[1]==0xD8)){

    //all good lets go!!
    while ((file[x]!=0xFF) && (file[x+1]!=0xE1)) {
       x++;
    }

    //were at the first EXIF data block! insert XML here
    char * temp=file;
    file = new char [filelen+yourdatalen+4];
    memcpy(file,temp,x);
    file[x+0]=0xFF;
    file[x+1]=0xE1;
    file[x+2]=int((yourdatalen+2)/0xFF); //note assumes that your xml file is less than 0xFFFE bytes long
    file[x+3]=yourdatalen-int((yourdatalen+2)/0xFF);
    memcpy(&file[x+4],yourdata,yourdatalen);
    memcpy(&file[x+4+yourdatalen],temp[x],filelen-x);
    delete [] temp;

    //Save to file
    std::ofstream ofile;
    ofile.open("savejpg.jpg",std::ios::binary| std::ios::out);
    ofile.write(file,yourdatalen+4+filelen);
    ofile.close();
}
else {
    //JPG file does not have exif data in it, you'll need to add it first or find another way of adding your data
}

//Clean up
delete [] file;
```

I used HxD but you can use any hex editor.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the maximum EXIF field size is 32KB, so this should be more than enough for doing an XML file.

Generate an ASCII C-string representation of your XML tree, using libxml2 perhaps. Then set the EXIF "User Comment" tag to that string.

The following example sets this tag: http://libexif.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/libexif/libexif/contrib/examples/write-exif.c?view=markup

I think that you need to use that ASCII_COMMENT prefix, and FILE_COMMENT would be your XML string.